# Is it possible to have offline translation for Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: kindle

Right now to translate word in Kindle Paperwhite I have to press on word, then I will see 3 popups(Dictionary, Wikipedia and Translation). For Translation - it is possible to use only when Kindle Paperwhite connected to WiFi as I see. Is there way to have translations in Flight Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. There no possibility to have Translation tab without WiFi, but you can download and set your dictionary(for your preferred language) as default. After that when you select word you will see popup with Dictionary and in fact it will work as translator. That way with your Dictionary will work in Flight Mode too.